# can litral control improve web page speed over label control

Tags: asp.net

i have grid that uses around 12 to 15 label when i bind it...and grid contains thousands of records, now if i'll use litral control instead of label will it help to improve the speed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably a lighter control but neither a `Label` or `Literal` control are that complex. You are better off looking at other solutions such as paging the data instead of rendering thousands of rows.

Answer (score 3):

The issue you are having is that you are displaying thousands of records in a grid on a webpage. The difference between using label or literal controls will not help this situation.

Rethink your design so you do not show thousands of records at once - use paging.

Answer (score 1):

What you gain by using a Literal instead of a Label is just that it renders the value without a span tag around it. That should give you a marginal speed improvment.

If you really need the speed, you should not use a Grid at all, but create the HTML code for the table yourself. Also using styled div elements instead of a table would reduce the size of the HTML considerably.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a test and measure execution time and memory required for the task, with Label, and with Literal.

Another approach would be to see what HTML code Label emits, and what does Literal emit. If I remember correctly, Label will add [span] tag around your string, and Literar will only write string without tags. That could mean, if you do not need span tag in your grid, that in your case you should probably use Literal.